# anyone tried installing ubuntu-desktop via ipxe/22.04 live iso subiquity method?

Tags: 22.04, live-cd, subiquity

Just recently, running a network ipxe install of Ubuntu 22.04 results in an error 100 when trying to install the ubuntu-desktop package. I can try and switch to xubuntu-desktop and while that allows my process to complete and boot the system, the environment is not really xubuntu, but rather a vanilla version of gnome with xubuntu login/shutdown screens and few other items.

It seems it can't install ubuntu-desktop automatically, I can get out of subiquity and into the OS with another DE and complete the install that way, but we'd much rather get ubuntu-desktop working instead. Editing the user-data used by the ipxe install method, I had the ubuntu-desktop as part of late commands and moved it to packages section (that's how I found it errors out on this package)
I'm not sure if anything different has happened to the package itself, it seems to install fine when you drop to a shell due to the error and manually run the Curtin in target command to install ubuntu-desktop.

I've done some searches for this online and I don't see many users running a similar setup or nothing issues like this. I'm also not sure as to what the error 100 means, but in other testing (by error really) I found that it may relate to a package it can't find? (Entered krb5-util and that gave error 100 error, should have been krb5-user)
Hopefully someone who knows more on subiquity automated installs can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: we need the actual message you get; not just the number.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].